# How can we prove that a three legged chair will never be wobbly?

Tags: geometry, 3d

I am taking the geometry approach. We know from intuition that more than three legs on a chair will make it unstable if any of the legs have a different length than the others. So by "wobble" I mean the possibility that at least one of the legs will be in the air when one or more legs are made shorter/longer than others. Also, the "surface" must be perfectly flat.

A three legged chair is unaffected by any amount of change we make to its legs. So to prove this I started out connecting lines between each legs (diagonals). So far I haven't made any progress.

For a triangle there are no diagonals. Is it enough to show that all the legs must be in the same plane for the chair to be stable?

Comment: A badly designed three-legged chair can fall over.

Comment: @Henry Nevertheless, it wouldn't wobble!

Comment: There is always a plane that passes through 3 points. Not so for more than 3 points.

Comment: You can have a chair with more than 3 unequal legs that isn't wobbly, if the surfaces of the feet touch a common plane.

Comment: The key fact is indeed that three points determine a plane, but connecting that to the stability of chairs requires a bit of elaboration that I don't have time for right now. Interestingly, a four-legged chair *can* be stable -- if one of the legs is sufficiently short and lies entirely inside the triangle formed by the other three.

Comment: Can you define "wobbly"?

Comment: @DavidQuinn I already did in the question.

Comment: @Rahul How can the fourth leg lie inside the triangle? Do you mean the centre of gravity? Still, that would be "wobbly" by the definition I gave.

Comment: In fact, even a [four-legged chair](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OuF-WB7mD6k) can always be rotated to be stable on any smooth floor.  The proof involves the intermediate value theorem.

Answer (score 3):

If “wobble” means “one leg in the air”, then “doesn't wobble” means “all legs touch the floor”. For a mathematician, it should be enough that all legs lie in the same plane, since you can rotate the chair in such a way that this plane coincides with the plane of the floor.

From an egineering point of view, you might have additional constraints like the center of gravity should be above the convex hull of the points touching the floor and so on, but that has little to do with the number of legs, and only affects whether your chair is likely to fall over instead of wobble.